# Can I use the Firebase ID token from a client login to authenticate a Java desktop app using the Java SDK?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

Google's Cloud Firestore can be accessed by **CLIENT** apps for iOS, Android, and web, via native SDKs.

For the **SERVER**, Cloud Firestore is also available in native Node.js, Java, Python, and Go SDKs, in addition to REST and RPC APIs. Of those, the Java and Node SDKs are capable of listening to changes in the database (as of March 2018).

I would like to use the Cloud Firestore in a **Java CLIENT desktop app**.

As I said, the Java Server SDK can listen to database changes, however it authenticates the user with Identity and Access Management (IAM), while the Client SDKs authenticate with Firebase Authentication. I must authenticate with Firebase Authentication, so that the database is protected with the Cloud Firestore Security Rules.

**My question is:** I want to log a user into one of the Firebase Client SDKs (web, iOS, or Android) and then send the ID token from that login to 
my Java desktop app. Then I want to authenticate the Java SDK with that token, thus limiting access with Cloud Firestore Security Rules.

Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Admin SDK, used on the server, doesn't support individual user logins.  You can see a list of what it can do related to authentication [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users).  To put it shortly, it's not meant for end-user applications, just backend support for client apps where the credentials used to initialize it are completely hidden and inaccessible to end users.

You would never ship a client app written with a the Admin SDK that also requires you to ship a service account credential to initialize it.  Service account credentials are like root passwords -- never give them to anyone except those that you trust with full access to everything.

Comment: The link you provided is about managing/creating users, when you login with a service account. It has nothing to do with what I want. I just want to know if you can login as a regular user instead of a service account, in the special case where I know the clients ID token. Also, please see the Java (not Android) code here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen . Is the Java code shown in this page from the Admin SDK?

Comment: Right, that doc saying that's *all* you can do with authentication with the admin SDK.  If it's not on that list, you can't do it.  You can't log in as a user.

Comment: The Firestore doc you linked has nothing to do with auth.  When you use the admin SDK to access Firestore, you can read and write everything, unconditionally.

Comment: I know the Firestore doc I linked has nothing to do with auth. I was just asking if that Java code is for the Admin SDK only. Or maybe it's for some other SDKs as well? Some SDKs I can use in a desktop app?... I think you fail to realize that my question is very basic. Nowhere in that page it says that the Java code is only to be used in the Admin SDK.

Comment: It's implied on all Firestore documentation that code samples in the "Java" tab are for the Admin SDK, and code in the "Android" tab is for Android.

Comment: If instead of "implied" it was clearly stated, maybe I would not be having this discussion with you.

Comment: Please feel free to file a bug report with your observations.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: I will, thanks. In any case, it seems to me that Google is going out of their way to prevent people from creating desktop apps with Firebase. It would be just too easy for them to allow for user auth in Java.

Comment: Desktop apps are out of scope for Firebase.  It's squarely aimed at mobile app development.  If you have a strong need for desktop app development, then add your voice as a feature request.  Though, to be honest, I don't see anything changing in the near future.